How to fix this error net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden) and outside of Vite serving allow list on nuxt project?
i'm have clone nuxt project from github (suppose project name is: Ex1). But I don't understand why when I run another project it's try to find Ex1 project.
This error on the browser console:
GET http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/C:/Users/.../Desktop/test/Ex1/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/entry.mjs net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
And this on my vscode console:
ERROR  The request url "C:\Users....\Desktop\test\Ex1\node_modules\nuxt\dist\app\entry.mjs" is outside of Vite serving allow list.
I think issue on the Ex1 project have to use "vite-pwa" then it's have effect to another project.
This is my nuxt.config.ts:
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  app: {
    head: {
      title: "PomoDo test",
      meta: [
        {
          name: "description",
          content:
            "PomoDo is a simple material-design pomodoro timer to help you focus.",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  css: ["vuetify/styles/main.sass", "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css"],
  build: {
    transpile: ["vuetify"],
  },
  modules: [
    "@vueuse/nuxt",
    "@vite-pwa/nuxt",
    [
      "@pinia/nuxt",
      {
        autoImports: ["defineStore", ["defineStore", "definePiniaStore"]],
      },
    ],
  ],
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      APP_VERSION: process.env.APP_VERSION,
    },
  },
  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      name: "PomoDo",
      short_name: "PomoDo",
      description: "A simple material design pomodoro timer to help you focus",
      icons: [
        {
          src: "icons/logo/256.png",
          sizes: "256x256",
          type: "image/png",
        },
        {
          src: "icons/logo/512.png",
          sizes: "512x512",
          type: "image/png",
        },
        {
          src: "icons/logo/1024.png",
          sizes: "1024x1024",
          type: "image/png",
        },
      ],
    },
    workbox: {
      navigateFallback: "/",
    },
    devOptions: {
      enabled: true,
      type: "module",
    },
  },
});

Please some one help me to fix this error.

Empty cache and hard reload seems to fix this issue temporarly
